# Multi-Conditional Selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select elements with multiple conditions, for example I'm doing the following at the moment:

```
$('#myspan').find('input:visible').each(myfunc);
```

Although I know you can do things like `$('#myspan input:visible')` but it didn't work for me.  I need to check for inputs within the span `#myspan` which are visible *and* are checked.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#myspan :checked:visible").each(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Gah, if only I could have multiple correct answers ;)  This one's good too.  How come you ommitted the input though?

Comment: You can put it in but it's implied by :checked (since only checkboxes can be checked and only inputs can be checkboxes). Up to you thought. I prefer terser expressions but putting in input:checked:visible is fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input:visible', '#myspan').find(':checked').each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Should do the trick. I like seperating things because I like to think it helps jQuery parse better.

Comment: It *is* faster to specify a context. Don't know why, but it seems to be so.

Comment: @Seb, the why is quite simple: without a context, the search starts from the root of the document ;)